# How To get value using Particular Key name In Firebase databse using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got stuck at a very awful point. I am developing a web application using firebase(for database) and Javascript.

Here is the structure of my firebase database.

[image]

and I want to display these categories in a dropdown input bar but in a way that every child category display within its parent category input bar in that way

This is what I want 
[image]

And this is my code

```
var newTask = firebase.database().ref("childCategory");
    newTask.on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var taskValue = childSnapshot.val();
            document.getElementById("selectCatigory").innerHTML +=
            <optgroup label="${taskValue.parentCategory}">
             snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
             var tasksValue = childSnapshot.val();
            document.getElementById("selectCatigory").innerHTML +=
            <option label="${tasksValue.childCName}"> </option> </optgroup>
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean that those bold values should not be selectable? And btw, what is the main issue you faced with here?

Comment: I want parent category in a bolded way and then its child category within it. like i have parent category  Software Engineering, and then we want all of the child categories which has value Software engineering and it should come inside bolded software engineering field.